# How do I know what the latest version of Google Play Services is for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I am adding Google Play Services to my gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
}
```

I know it is not good practice to use that + sign.
What is the best way to add the Google Play dependency that ensures that I am running the latest version?
It might be a dumb question, if so, please tell me what is wrong with my reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it inside your sdk folder.

```
androidsdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

Curently the last version is 7.8.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

You can also read the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) about the library. In this case, pay attention to update your SDK Manager when a new version is released.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify the exact version number like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Android Studio will mark the line with a warning when a newer version is available, and tell you what the new version is in the tooltip.